# Save React-Bootstrap xs,sm,md,lg,xl spans/offsets into css class

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

We have the following `<Row>` with 2 `<Col>` elements as such:

```
<Row>
    <Col xs={12} sm={{ span: 9, offset: 1 }} md={{ span: 6, offset: 0 }} lg={5} xl={4}>
        <h3 className='graph-header-1'>First Header</h3>
        <div>Graph that fills the col-width goes here</div>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={12} sm={{ span: 9, offset: 1 }} md={{ span: 6, offset: 0 }} lg={{ span: 5, offset: 1 }} xl={{ span: 4, offset: 2 }}>
        <h3 className='graph-header-1'></h3>
        <div>2nd Graph that fills the column's width goes here</div>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

This layout (row with 2 cols, with these specific spans / offsets for each of xs,sm,md,lg,xl) will be used in a few places in our app. Is it possible to save this in a class so that, rather than setting these values over and over again, we simply use:

```
<Row className='our-responsive-layout'>
    <Col>
        <h3 className='graph-header-1'>First Header</h3>
        <div>Graph that fills the col-width goes here</div>
    </Col>
    <Col>
        <h3 className='graph-header-1'></h3>
        <div>2nd Graph that fills the column's width goes here</div>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

...where `our-responsive-layout` is a class that handles the spans / offsets for the 2 columns? Alternatively, having a class for each column (rather than 1 class for the row for the 2 columns) would be helpful as well.

**Edit:** if there are any thorough guides on handling responsiveness in a complex react-app using react-bootstrap and their container / row / column components, please share. I am worried that adding things like `xs={12} sm={{ span: 9, offset: 1 }} md={{ span: 6, offset: 0 }} lg={{ span: 5, offset: 1 }} xl={{ span: 4, offset: 2 }}` throughout our app with make the code much messier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply create a component for this ? something [like that (demo)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-rxvosn) :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyRow>
      <MyCol>Here is your col 1</MyCol>
      <MyCol>Here is your col 2</MyCol>
    </MyRow>
  );
};

const MyRow = ({children}) => {
  return <div className='this is your row'>{children}</div>
}

const MyCol = ({children}) => {
  return <div className='this is your col'>{children}</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here you just replace `div` tags (and the className of course) in `MyRow` and `MyCol` with your rows and col components and it should be enough.

If you want to add or change classes on a col for example, you can just add an prop.

Comment: this may be a dumb question but it's not something I've ever been familiar with - whatever is passed inside the component: `Here is your col 1` in the example above, is automatically / always available to `MyCol` as `children`?

Comment: @Canovice Yes, that's how component works in React. There is two ways to call a component : `<MyCol />` (self closed) and `<MyCol>blabla</MyCol>` (..not self closed ? haha). Here, whatever you pass inside the non-self-closed version is retrieved inside `children`. It can be simple text but also other component (As for `MyRow`).

Comment: Okay thanks. Whenever I've needed to pass anything to a component, I've always passed it as a prop. I'm not sure what the benefit of `children` is over explicitly named props but I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: @Canovice You're welcome :) It prevent using props, it is also way easier to read in you jsx, and of course, children can accept whatever you want. Actually, `children` is a prop, you just don't need to declare it because React already know it. I use this kind of component for architectural behavior most of the time.